# Is it possible to make "Project Bookmarks" the default when adding a bookmark in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, bookmarks

Whenever I add a new bookmark in QGIS (3.14), I have to change the `Saved in` dropdown from User bookmarks to Project bookmarks. Is it possible to make Project the default?

The User bookmark doesn't even make any sense to me, so I don't know why it is the default. Why would anyone even want to save a bookmark that is not related to some GIS data?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer ! If someone have an idea... Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a nice feature request to QGIS.

Comment: I'm on QGIS 3.26.2 and it defaults to Project Bookmark for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but luckily it was implemented.

Starting from QGIS 3.26, the [Spatial bookmark is saved under the Project Bookmarks](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-rename-bookmark-groups-context-menu-control) not `User Bookmarks`

If you go to `View → New Spatial Bookmark` (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + b), you will find the bookmarks are saved under the `Project Bookmarks` by default.

[image]